# Pandas dataframe filter on non na value in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter, na

I have about 4 columns and need to keep the rows where atleast one of the columns has value in addition to the ID column

the first column is ID column and is never null

| ID | column A | column B | column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 |  | 199 | 222 |
| 02 | 50 |  |  |
| 03 |  |  |  |
| 04 |  | 20 |  |
| 05 |  |  |  |

output

| ID | column A | column B | column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 |  | 199 | 222 |
| 02 | 50 |  |  |
| 04 |  | 20 |  |

Comment: `df.dropna(thresh=2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a reproductible example next time.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'column A':[2,np.nan,2,np.nan],
                   'column B':[3,np.nan,np.nan,2],
                   'column C':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', subset=list(df.columns[df.columns != 'ID']))
```

`axis=0` : rows

`how='all'` : completly `nan` values

`subset=` : to specify on which column you want to apply it

Answer (score 0):

You should have checked the documentation: [`pandas.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['','',''],[11,'',''],['','',22],['','','']])
>>> df
    0 1   2
0          
1  11      
2        22
3          
>>> df.loc[[any(row) for row in df.values]]
    0 1   2
1  11      
2        22
```